# Codeigniter pagination class - how to remove a trailing slash from URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've noticed the following behavior in CI's pagination class:

My initial page (used as `$config['base_url']`):

```
http://www.example.com/forum
```

When I paginate to page 2 (per_page = 10, offset = 10, total_rows = 100):

```
http://www.example.com/forum/10
```

When I go back to Page 1:

```
http://www.example.com/forum/  <=====trailing slash
```

This trailing slash is messing up several Ajax commands in the page.

Any idea how to make it go away?

Comment: When you're on /10 or /20, aren't the AJAX commands messed up as well? The best solution is to fix your AJAX urls.

Comment: use `$this->uri->segment(1)` in your ajax urls (possible slash removing needed, did not test it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for that:

```
trim( $the_url, '/' );
```